# How to render index based JSON data via handlebars?

Tags: arrays, json, handlebars.js

I have a JSON structure in the following format:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title": "Title",
        "carouselName": {
            "id": [
                "carousel-1",
                "carousel-2",
                "carousel-3"
            ],
            "carouselImage": [
                "images/carousel-1.jpg",
                "images/carousel-2.jpg",
                "images/carousel-3.jpg"
            ],
            "carouselSubTitle": [
                "Sub Title 1",
                "Sub Title 2",
                "Sub Title 3"
            ],
            "breadText": [
                "Bread Text 1",
                "Bread Text 2",
                "Bread Text 3"
            ],
            "productUrl": [
                "#",
                "#",
                "#"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any built-in handlebar helper for rendering the data of this type? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt helper to achieve the same. However, you can use the in-built each helper to render the same. For instance, as follows:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{properties.title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{#each properties.carouselName}}
      {{#each this}}
        <h5>{{this}}</h5>
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```